# How to listen events in react/angular/vue from stencils components

Tags: stenciljs, stencil-component

I have created simple one component in stencils.js and I used that in react/angular/vue. From my stencil component i have emit an event. This event is captured in angular/react/vue.
My problem is I need to use the same component twice in a single html. How I can identify the which event is emitted by which component instance ?

Comment: can share the code to support your question

Comment: You should be able to use `event.target`.

Comment: Or try adding metadata when you emit an event. Is bubbles option set to true?

Answer (score 0):

Using `@stencil/react-output-target` library and following [this guide](https://stenciljs.com/docs/react) you will be able to do this:

```
//button component
import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'button-component',
  styleUrl: 'button.css',
  shadow: false,
  scoped: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() label: string;

  render() {
    return <button type="button">{this.label}</button>;
  }
}

// button component instance in React
<ButtonComponent label='Test Button' onClick={() => alert("Hi, I'm a button alert!")}/>
```

Just found it after hours of trying to pass a function inside of Stencil component...